# Yii2 enable form submit on error with client validation

Tags: javascript, validation, yii2, client-side

I am building Yii2 form and did setup just client side validation for user experience to confirm text length.
I would like the user still to be able to submit the form even on error from this field.

The code I added:

```
    <?php
    $this->registerJs('
    jQuery("#' . $form->getId() . '").yiiActiveForm("add", {
        "id": "description",
        "name": "description",
        "container": ".field-description",
        "input": "#description",
        "validate": function(attribute, value, messages, deferred, $form) {
            yii.validation.required(value, messages, {
                "message": "Description cannot be blank."
            });
            yii.validation.string(value, messages, {
                "message": "Description must be a string.",
                "min": 135,
                "tooShort": "Description should contain at least 135 characters.",
                "max": 160,
                "tooLong": "Description should contain at most 160 characters.",
                "skipOnEmpty": 1
            });
        }
    });
    ', View::POS_LOAD); 
    ?>
```

So far the only success I got is by adding

```
  'validateOnSubmit'=>false
```

to the $form options. But this skips errors from the other fields also

Comment: remove particular field from Model validation rules.

Comment: yes, it is only in the view, dont need php to validate it

Comment: What you can do ,  have two different scenarioes , scenario1 clientValidation and second serverValidation , When u render have scenaruio clientValidation and at server after loading data to post have scenario serverValidation and remove that fields in clientValidation. I hyope you get what i am trying to say.